# Handle "dont ask again " Location Permissions Xamarin Forms

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, permissions, location

I got this dilemma. I am using TK-TORBEN-Maps ,Xamarin Forms. I did implement all the runtime permissions . however, if an user clicks "dont ask me again" what can I do to stop the app from crashing. 
I need to let them pass even if they didnt accept and the first page is the map. is there anyway I could still display the map with those permission being denied?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you could not use the map without the permission.
I think you could explain to your users why the app needs the permission. For example, you could use `ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationale`.

```
      string permission = Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation;
      if (ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permission))
      {
        //Explain to the user why we need to read the contacts
        Snackbar.Make(layout, "Location access is required for some reason ", Snackbar.LengthIndefinite)
                .SetAction("OK", v => RequestPermissions(PermissionsLocation, RequestLocationId))
                .Show();
        return;
      }
```

You could refer to this [blog](https://blog.xamarin.com/requesting-runtime-permissions-in-android-marshmallow/) for more information.

If you want the app not crash, you could try to navigate to another page after user denies the request.

Comment: Thanks Billy for the answer . I have all already. but you know I will always have that user that will go to settings and turn off location . and I could ask a million times . if they just click no , or dont show again . it is out my hands . all I could do is prevent the crash somehow.  if I get to this scenario.